# Weighted degree according to Opsahl et al. (2010)

Tags: r, networking, graph

I want to calculate weighted degree for a network that I am working with. To do so, I want to use the `degree_w` function proposed by Opsahl et al. (2010). Before using it with my network, I wanted to play with it a little bit with a toy model to get a better feel for it.

However, it turned out that no matter what I choose for the tuning parameter alpha, `degree_w` remains insensitive to it. When I calculate it with `alpha = 1` I get the same values as for standard `degree` (which is expected). The problem is that when I try to use `alpha = 0.5` or `alpha = 1.5` the values don't change. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my model:

```
library("tnet")
net <- cbind(c(1,1,2,2,2,3), c(2,3,3,4,5,2), c(2,1,2,1,3,2))
degree_w(net, alpha = 1.0)
     node degree output
[1,]    1      2      3
[2,]    2      3      6
[3,]    3      1      2
[4,]    4      0      0
[5,]    5      0      0
> degree_w(net, alpha = 1.5)
     node degree output
[1,]    1      2      3
[2,]    2      3      6
[3,]    3      1      2
[4,]    4      0      0
[5,]    5      0      0
degree_w(net, alpha = 0.5)
     node degree output
[1,]    1      2      3
[2,]    2      3      6
[3,]    3      1      2
[4,]    4      0      0
[5,]    5      0      0
```

Comment: Why the `igraph` label?

Comment: It should be `tnet` but I can't create new labels yet. I changed it to just `R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
degree_w(net, alpha = 1.0,measure="alpha")
```

The documentation about this function is not very good.